# Error installing .Net Core on Ubuntu VM : "dotnet restore" fails in CurlHandler.SetProxyOptions()

Tags: .net, ubuntu, curl, nuget, coreclr

On an Ubuntu 14.04 VMWare VM the simple instructions at:
  [https://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/][1] 
worked fine until the following step:

> dotnet restore

Here's the call stack that throws the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The value cannot be null or empty.   
Parameter name: UserName 
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.EasyRequest.SetProxyOptions(Uri requestUri) 
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.EasyRequest.InitializeCurl() 
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)  
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()   
at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.HttpSource.<GetAsync>d__11.MoveNext() 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() 
at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.Restore.NuGet.NuGetv2Feed.<FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext()

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RemoteWalkProvider.<FindLibrary>d__6.MoveNext() 
... 
at Microsoft.Dnx.Tooling.RestoreCommand.<Execute>d__68.MoveNext()
```

> curl http://www.google.com

works fine, so the proxy for curl is configured correctly (/etc/environment contains http_proxy="..." definitions)

I don't have any web proxy credentials configured anywhere, so it's unclear why nuget or the RestoreCommand is configuring curl with invalid "empty" credentials.

If nuget would leave the credentials null curl should function fine as it does on the command line since SetProxyOptions() handles that case fine:

```
NetworkCredential credential = CurlHandler.GetCredentials(this._handler.Proxy.Credentials, this._requestMessage.RequestUri).get_Key();
if (credential != null)
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a defect in the dotnet dnx tools but in my case I was able to work around the defect.  I expect a fix will will be in place by RTM as this was an RC build of dot net core.

The Nuget.HttpSource constructor assigns the credentials as follows when the environment variable "http_proxy" is in the simple (non-username) format:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(environmentVariable); 
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(environmentVariable); 
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.UserName)) 
{ 
   proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
}
```

DefaultCredentials is set to an immutable set of empty Credentials:

```
SystemNetworkCredential.s_defaultCredential = new SystemNetworkCredential();

private SystemNetworkCredential() : base(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty) {}
```

Since SetProxyOptions() checks the credential using:

```
if (credential != null)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(credential.UserName))
      throw ...
```

And the UserName is Empty it will always throw an exception.

If instead it were to check using:

```
if (credential != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(credential.UserName))
   // do cred work
```

Then all would be well.  Null or default credentials (e.g. SystemDefaultCredentials which are immutably empty) would be treated as "no credentials".

Otherwise Microsoft could change the DNX tool to leave the credentials null instead of using the SystemDefaultCredentials.  This is a simple case of the caller and callee disagreeing on the protocol for specifying a lack of credentials (null ref vs. ref with empty strings).

In my case the workaround I used was to fill in a bogus credential so that the dnx tool wouldn't throw.  Luckily my proxy server didn't complain about the unwanted and invalid credential.

Comment: I ran into this issue with the Docker `microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr` image. Your workaround did the trick: `dnu restore -p http://user:pass@proxy.example.com:12345`

Answer (score 0):

Using an authenticated proxy works for me: `RUN dnu restore -p http://user:pass@proxy.name.com`. I'm building an image `From:microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-final-coreclr`